# What is the role for a controller and what is the role for $scope in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am an AngularJS noob but very familiar with previous MVC/MVVM frameworks. I come from an OO background but have invested a fair amount of time learning the quasi-functional nature of Javascript. Let's say that I understand closures without ever having made meaningful use of them.

I am trying to get clarity on the difference between the controller concept and the $scope concept in AngularJS.

Below I am careful when I use the '$scope' object versus referring to the concept of 'scope' in AngularJS.

In the AngularJS Conceptual Overview (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts) controllers are described as using scopes as the glue between the view and the controller. The scope seems something like a model container.

This makes sense.

What doesn't make sense is all of the examples I've seen where functions are added to the $scope object. Is the $scope object the body of the controller? If so, isn't this object inaptly named as it confuses with the 'scope' concept?

-Liking-AngularJS-But-Confused

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The $scope is an object that both the view and the controllers know...

It's not actually the controller itself, but through it you can pass in references to data and methods and use them inside of the view.

The controller in angular is more like a presentation model, which holds up an object which is a "mutual friend" of both the view and the controller... that's how I like to think of it at least :)

Comment: Thanks! So business logic particular to a view goes in the controller or in $scope? Are these one in the same thing? I see people adding methods to $scope.

Comment: When you want to expose something to the view you attach it to the $scope, other methods for data transformations you can put inside the controller's, but usually it will find itself on the $scope after all the calculations or transformations :)

Comment: Thanks again! So say manipulation of JSON objects from the server would be in the controller, but code to change the background of a div would be in $scope?

Comment: Not exactly, you should only express data on the $scope, and call $scope methods from the view (one way), code like jQuery manipulation should be inside of directives, and usually changes to Json, if they are local to you controller could be there, but if they are globally needed, they should be in an injectable service

Comment: Ahh very good. I see. Ok. So controllers are really just for very view-oriented code. They are not intended to me something like a overall controller for application behavior or operations. I am going to mark this question as answered (and ask another one specific to that!). Thanks very much ShaiRez!